# Create a key value pair of maps in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is the below code giving me this error?

**Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast**

I am trying to create a map with contactname as the key and phone numbers as values -

```
  void mapContacts() {
    String contact = 'Test';
    List<String> phones = ['4160000000', '7780000000'];
    var maps = <String, List<String>>{};
    maps['Name'] = contact;
    maps['phones'] = phones;

    print(maps);
  }
```

Comment: This is not what Map was designed for.  Please create proper objects that have a contact string, and a phones list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the Map as follows:

```
Map<String, dynamic> maps = {
      'name': contact,
      'phones': ['phone1','phone2'],
    };
```

This is because your map is expecting a string as a key and string as values of those keys, while you are trying to set the, phones field, as a List.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. But if you have lots of users and phone numbers, you may map each user the way I showed you and add it to a list of the same type.